# TSC_DEADLINE disabled error even after updating microcode

Tags: 16.04, intel, microcode

I got the following error:

[image]

So, I logged into `root shell` and installed the `intel-microcode` package:

`sudo apt-get install microcode.ctl intel-microcode`

But I still receive the error after rebooting. I logged into `root shell` again and checked the version of microcode:
[image]

As you see I have version `0xb000021` which is newer than`0xb000020` but I still get the same error and can't boot normally.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you forget to update initrams with `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` ? Then reboot.

Comment: @N0rbert yes, should I have done it? Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: I think it should help. Current initramfs may not contain new ucode.

Comment: @N0rbert will try tomorrow and let you know, thanks.

Comment: @N0rbert doesn't work. Still getting the first error...